# End Session in all browser after logout.php

Tags: javascript, php

I currenly have this on my logout.php

```html
<?php
//LOGOUT.PHP
session_start(); 

//// unset all $_SESSION variables
session_regenerate_id();
session_unset();
session_destroy();

$_SESSION['logoutsuccess'] = 'You have successfully logged out.';
header("Location: index.php");
exit;
```

But after changing password using changepassword.php that has logout.php in the end. It just destroy the session on current tab. But it doesn't destroy the session on the other browser/tab. TIA!

Comment: `$_SESSION = array();` is another way to reset the session data, your above example is setting one key of an array.

Comment: Are you talking about tabs in the *same* browser? That part's not possible unless you install an addon: cookies as browser-wide, not tab specific. You must be getting your diagnostics wrong. (Unless you mean that the tabs are not refreshed automatically, something that of course can't happen with pure server-side code.)

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
$_SESSION = array(); 
session_destroy(); 
setcookie (session_name(), '', time()-3600);
```

Comment: Sir, I would like to ask if I should add something ti session_name(), 'addsmthng', or i should just try to do that? bcoz i tried to add something to the name. And Im still lost T_T

Comment: @ErickSanPascual You do not need to add anything to the `session_name()`.

Comment: Im testing it with chrome and incognito of it. even if i add something in name or not adding anything on it. It sill doesn't logout the account in incognito. Even refresh, that's what im messing with.

Comment: @ErickSanPascual You are creating a session variable after `session_destroy()`.

Comment: @ErickSanPascual May be you are messing with something else. This is the standard code for logout systems and I've used this for years without any problem.

Comment: The issue here is essentially cross browser. While this will close out the session for the current browser, It would not work if you were in say Chrome and Safari and logged out in Chrome, Safari would remain logged in. The OP is looking for a way to log out both is what im thinking.

Comment: @ErickSanPascual Are you talking about different browsers or different modes of the same browser such as private or normal? If so, it is easier than you might think. Store some kind of identifier to the database if the user logs out. Check for that identifier in your main configuration file and if that is set redirect to logout page. The logout page hopefully redirects back to `index.php`. In this way you can log out in every device and every browser no matter what or which. But you can add a checkbox also to tell the user to log out of every devices.

Comment: @ErickSanPascual I like to ask the user whether the user wants to log out of every devices or not. This way the user may log in without needing to add username and password again in the user's favorite device, only if you have given that feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
 //LOGOUT.PHP
session_start(); 

//// destroy all $_SESSION variables

session_destroy();

echo "<script>alert('You have successfully logged out.')</script>";
echo "<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";
```

Comment: Yap, Im already using session_destroy. But didnt destroy other tab or websites session.

Answer (score 0):

What you are attempting to do isn't easy when it comes to pure PHP. Javascript will be your friend in a situation like this.

If I were to implement this I would create something in JS that checks every x amount of seconds/minutes with the backend to see if the password has changed. This will require a separate endpoint that is specifically for this check.

Here would be a rough outline of what I would consider doing:

- When the user logs in take the username and hashed password to create a hash of that data using something like `$userAuthHash = sha1("{$username}${password_hash})` and save that in the user session.
- In your page (in the header more than likely) display the created hash. This is generally best to do in a meta tag in the header (ex: `<meta name="user_auth_hash" content="<?php echo $userAuthHash; ?>">`). You can obviously set this up however you want as long as you can look it up using JS.
- Have the JS script get the value of the hash from the meta tag and every x interval send this to the validation endpoint. The endpoint should in some way indicate if the users token is still valid.
- If the users token is no longer valid you can have the JS script redirect the user to the logout script as needed.

There are a lot more complex ways of doing this but this is one of the easiest ways of going about this that I know of.

Also remember not to over think these things when building software. Security is important but imagine the case where an account gets hacked and the hacking party changes the password. Your now legitimate user has been logged out and thats never any good. This would be a case where you would need to evaluate your initial strategy and possibly implement an email that forces the user to validate a password change before it is persisted to the database. Just some food for thought.

Comment: Thank you for the comment sir I would try to do this.